# My app gets an unexpected error an forces me to shut it down....what seems to be the problem?

Tags: java, android, android-mapview

BlobCity.java:

```
package BlobCity.xyz.com;

import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class BlobCity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button signIn,register;
    TextView Blob,City,username,password;
    EditText eUsername,ePassword;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        signIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signIn);  
        register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);

        Blob = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.blob);
        City = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.city);
        username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.password);

        eUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eUsername);
        ePassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ePassword);

        signIn.setOnClickListener(new sendUserPass());
        register.setOnClickListener(new regPage());         

    }

    class sendUserPass implements Button.OnClickListener
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {       
        String uname = eUsername.getText().toString();
        String pwd = ePassword.getText().toString();
        String requestString = ("http://192.168.1.102:8080/BlobCity/RemoteLogin?email="+ uname + "&pwd=" + pwd);
        String line;

        try {                                                                                                                                         
            HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(new HttpGet(requestString));
            InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder rb = new StringBuilder("");

            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    rb.append(line) ;                                       
                }
                if(rb.toString().equals("0"))
                {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a valid Username and/or Password!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                    eUsername.setText("");
                    ePassword.setText("");
                }
                else
                { 
                   setContentView(R.layout.map);
                   eUsername.setText("");
                   ePassword.setText("");

                }
            }

            catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
            {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }             
        }
    }

    class regPage implements Button.OnClickListener
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
             Intent browse = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse("http://www.blobcity.com") );
             startActivity(browse);                 
        }
    }
}
```

============================================================================

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget35"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#d2691e">

    <TextView
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:layout_x="75px"
        android:layout_y="25px"
        android:id="@+id/blob"
        android:text="Blob"
        android:layout_width="144px"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    <TextView
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:layout_x="158px"
        android:layout_y="25px"
        android:id="@+id/city"
        android:text="City"
        android:layout_width="144px"
        android:layout_height="57px"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

    <TextView
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_x="110px"
        android:layout_y="120px"
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:text="Username"
        android:layout_width="144px"
        android:layout_height="40px"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_x="55px"
        android:layout_y="150px"
        android:id="@+id/eUsername"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="200px"
        android:layout_height="40px"
        android:textSize="15sp"/> 

    <TextView
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_x="110px"
        android:layout_y="190px"
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:text="Password"
        android:layout_width="144px"
        android:layout_height="40px"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_x="55px"
        android:layout_y="220px"
        android:id="@+id/ePassword"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="200px"
        android:layout_height="40px"
        android:textSize="15sp" /> 

    <Button
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_x="55px"
        android:layout_y="290px"
        android:id="@+id/signIn"
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:layout_width="200px"
        android:layout_height="40px"
        android:textColor="#000080"/> 

    <Button
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_x="55px"
        android:layout_y="340px"
        android:id="@+id/register"
        android:text="Register Now for FREE"
        android:layout_width="200px"
        android:layout_height="40px"
        android:textColor="#000080"/>  
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

======================================================================

myMapView.java:

```
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.*;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public abstract class myMapView extends MapActivity{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

MapView mapView;      

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                     
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.getController().setZoom(20);
    }
}
```

==============================================================================

map.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dip"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="the_key_that_i_have" />
</LinearLayout>
```

=======================================================================

manifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="BlobCity.xyz.com"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
       <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity android:name=".BlobCity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Post you logcat pls

Comment: print error log then we can verify actually issue and possible please re-format code.

Answer (score 3):

1. Your package `package="BlobCity.xyz.com"` seem to be written backwards. Should be `package="com.xyz.BlobCity"` and should be your actual package where your activity class `BlobCity` is.
2. Make sure you [create your Maps API Key](http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html)? You have to put it here:

   ```
   android:apiKey="example_Maps_ApiKey_String"
   ```

**Edited:**

You should not run your long running tasks (networking) inside event handlers. This blocks redrawing of the UI (app seems unresponsive) and can finally lead to [ANR error](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html). Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to run your networking code in the background.

Comment: ya...i have the key..theres no issue with that

Comment: and the "package="BlobCity.xyz.com"" is auto-generated by the IDE

Comment: yes, but you entered it somewhere during the project setup process

Comment: Also, please put some effort in formating your code - put 4 spaces at the beginning of the line to be formatted as code

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Where in code does it happen?

Comment: it just causes the program to unexpectedly close

Comment: Probably found the source to the problem - look at the edited answer

Comment: the problem is not that the app doesnt respond...it is that, it just stops unexpectedly

Comment: Do you see anything in the logcat?

Comment: wtf? is it too hard to create a simple class? AsyncTask is a good practice - Google wrote it just for cases like this. You should learn it because you will use it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to get hold of the stack trace where your application fails. It always helps a lot.

Second, do you really want the class `myMapView` to be abstract? If not, remove the abstract keyword.

Third, your manifest states the application has one activity: `BlobCity.xyz.com.BlobCity` but the source code you are showing is for class `myMapView` (can't tell in which package).

The `android:name` attribute in the activity tag within the manifest should point to a class that implements the activity, which isn't that case here. Either change the attribute or add a a new activity tag which points to the class mentioned above.

From what I can see I would guess you are stating that the class `BlobCity` exists in the package `BlobCity.xyz.com.`, but when the system tries to find the class it is nowhere to be found.

Comment: removing the keyword "abstract" gives me an error:The type myMapView must implement the inherited abstract method MapActivity.isRouteDisplayed()

Comment: and now i've just given out my complete project...so you might understand why the android:name attribute is pointing to blobcity